# make <input type="file"> element fill up its parent <div>

Tags: html, css

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <img src="some/path/" class="thumbnail" />
  <input type="file" class="image_upload" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div
{
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail
{
  width: 100%;
}
.image_upload
{
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I want `<img>` and `<input type="file">` to overlap with each other and both fill up their parent `<div>`. How can I fix my CSS to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to change the size of a file input. You could [redesign the file-input and](http://shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom), but the size of the clickable area isn't modifiable.

**Edit:** Aaron shows a first trick, and I added the second one, so see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJWcs/2/) in which the whole image is clickable for the file input.

The trick is to set `font-size` to a large value, then `opacity` to zero and finally add `overflow: hidden` to the parent element.

Comment: Thanks. I like your use of `font-size`, `opacity:0`, and `overflow:hidden` but I find `line-height` unnecessary.

Comment: Oh, I see. If `font-size` is set, `line-height` can be omitted.

Answer (score 6):

File input fields don't really play by the rules (or at least as you'd expect). To accomplish what it sounds like you're after, you've gotta get creative. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZTPCd/

Comment: Perfect! You disproved my answer. [See this one](http://jsfiddle.net/pJWcs/), in which the whole image is clickable.

Answer (score 4):

Its Possible.

Add this css for input type file

```
.My_CSS {
    opacity: 0; 
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: grey;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;    
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add relative positioning to the parent `div`, so the `input` field won't be positioned relatively to the browser window. (Google for more info about absolute/relative positioning).

And you'll have to add some specific positioning (top/left) to the `input` tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/NbhQY/

(Your outer `div` will have to be a little bit bigger, though, if it needs to include a file upload.)

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to use some JavaScript. Since I don't see any way to change the CSS for input(type=file) itself, I made it hidden but the `<div>` responsible for `<input type='file'>`.

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var file = document.getElementById("file");

box.addEventListener('click', function(){
 file.click();
})
```

```css
#box {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    position: relative;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  color: white;
}

#file {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
    <img id="image" src="http://guide.denverpost.com/media/photos/full/mountain_600x600.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    <input type="file" id="file"/>
    <p>Click to import</p>
</div>
```